# The v3 API of consumption.azure.com fails to return the offerId most of the time

Tags: azure

When I fetch the Azure Pricing Sheet from

```
https://consumption.azure.com/v3/enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/pricesheet
```

the returned JSON is a price list of all Azure components. The list sometimes returns the value for offerId (`MS-AZR-0017P` or `MS-AZR-0148P`), but most of the time the value is NULL for all returned records.

**Problem**: Every meterId is mentioned twice in the list, and it's the offerId that determines the correct price. Without the offerId I can't determine which of both rows with the same meterId is the one with the correct unitPrice and partNumber.

**Attempt 1** (successful):

```
    "offerId": "MS-AZR-0017P",
    "id": "enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingperiods/201907/products/1001543/pricesheets",
    "billingPeriodId": "201907",
    "meterId": "b28a9f2d-9323-4021-8421-db9e3847a535",
    "meterName": "Virtual Machines A Series Basic Windows - A2 - KR South",
    "unitOfMeasure": "100 Hours",
    "includedQuantity": 0.0000,
    "partNumber": "AAA-38759",
    "unitPrice": 12.3100,
    "currencyCode": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "offerId": "MS-AZR-0148P",
    "id": "enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingperiods/201907/products/1001544/pricesheets",
    "billingPeriodId": "201907",
    "meterId": "b28a9f2d-9323-4021-8421-db9e3847a535",
    "meterName": "Virtual Machines A Series Basic Windows - A2 - Dev/Test - KR South",
    "unitOfMeasure": "100 Hours",
    "includedQuantity": 0.0000,
    "partNumber": "AAA-38881",
    "unitPrice": 8.1800,
    "currencyCode": "EUR"
  },
```

**Attempt n** (unsuccessful):

```
    "offerId": null,
    "id": "enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingperiods/201907/products/1001543/pricesheets",
    "billingPeriodId": "201907",
    "meterId": "b28a9f2d-9323-4021-8421-db9e3847a535",
    "meterName": "Virtual Machines A Series Basic Windows - A2 - KR South",
    "unitOfMeasure": "100 Hours",
    "includedQuantity": 0.0000,
    "partNumber": "AAA-38759",
    "unitPrice": 12.3100,
    "currencyCode": "EUR"
  },
  {
    "offerId": null,
    "id": "enrollments/{enrollmentNumber}/billingperiods/201907/products/1001544/pricesheets",
    "billingPeriodId": "201907",
    "meterId": "b28a9f2d-9323-4021-8421-db9e3847a535",
    "meterName": "Virtual Machines A Series Basic Windows - A2 - Dev/Test - KR South",
    "unitOfMeasure": "100 Hours",
    "includedQuantity": 0.0000,
    "partNumber": "AAA-38881",
    "unitPrice": 8.1800,
    "currencyCode": "EUR"
  },
```

I tried fetching the JSON several times with Postman and in Azure Data Factory with a REST call, but there does not seem to be a pattern or a reliable way to get the list including the offerId every time.
Because I want to use this information in my DWH I need a reliable and predictable response from the API.

I expect the API to return reliable and predictable information, containing the correct offerId on every record every time I query the API

**To do**: I'm going to create a support ticket in the Azure portal as soon as I get the permission to do that to find out if this is a known bug or something I did wrong.

The documentation for the v3 version is not up-to-date. Documentation on this specific endpoint was last updated april 2017:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-pricesheet`

and it mentions the older v2 version.

The documentation on the UsageDetails page:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/enterprise/billing-enterprise-api-usage-detail`

was updated march 2019 and mentions the v3 version.

The big difference between the v2 and v3 response for `PriceSheet` is that v3 also returns the `offerId` which makes it possible to determine the correct `unitPrice` and `partNumber` which is mentioned on the invoice. To be able to cross-reference the invoice details with the actual usage you need to know the correct `partNumber` and for that you need the `offerId`.

There is another solution, but it requires quite some work in changing the current setup. At the moment I use the Azure export function to get usagedetails exported to CSV files every 24 hours. The files are imported into the DWH and transformed further. But the records in the CSV do not contain the partNumber. The v3 usagedetails endpoint does return the partNumber...

**Summary**: I'll create an Azure support ticket and wait for an answer. In the meantime I'll try to figure out why the API returns different results.

**Question**: Who has had similar issues with the consumption API's and how did you work around them?

**Question**: What might be the cause of an API returning different results?

Comment: This reads like a bug-report rather than a question - and this is not the right place for bug-reports...

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. The reason why I posted this question here is because I understood from a Microsoft employee that this platform is monitored very closely by the product groups and therefore a very effective way of bringing this to their attention. But if you could share your experience by bringing a more effective way to my attention I'd be grateful.

Comment: Whatever Microsoft may indicate - this question is a bad fit for the site and MS should do a better job to guide their users to an appropriate location to spare them a  bad user experience...

Comment: I agree on that last comment, they should do a better job. But that's not actually what I meant by sharing a more effective way. So I'll just wait for a more appropriate answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @piet.t even if it is a bug related question, they may be some users who found some workarounds so I don't see why you think this question is not valid.

Comment: @Thomas the thing is: I can't find any question in there! Do you?

Comment: @piet.t yeah make sense :-). mdmaarschalk could you rephrase your question please or give more details on what you would like the community to help you on ?

Comment: Statusupdate: Microsoft is still working on this bug, they were able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another price sheet api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/pricesheet/get

It is queried at the subscription level instead of the enrollment, so to get a complete price sheet for your enrollment, you'll have to make a separate request per subscription with a different offer id.